# How to Find Duplicate Pairs

Tags: excel

I’m using Excel xlsx and I have two columns with addresses and I want to find the duplicates for the street number and name pair in column E (see screenshot) with any duplicate street/name pairs in column F.

**For example:**

```
 3000 El Camino Blvd
```

...with any duplicate:

```
 3000 El Camino Blvd
```

...in entire Column F. The problem is the formula:

```
=IF(E1<=F1,E1 & " | " & F1,F1 & " | " & E1)
```

...did not show any highlighted entries after I entered it into the conditional format - new rule section.

I’m not sure if Excel can capture the unique pairs of addresses street #/name together to match duplicates pairs. Any suggestions?

[image: screenshot link]

Comment: do you just want want to *remove* the duplicates?

Comment: I just want to find them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a suggestion, use match(), it returns the position number in the list of the matching item - I used col B as the things to find and match returns the position in col A - note it is not the row number but the position of the item in the list.

[image: match example]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) function. In column G, you can use the formula below to see if column F has any occurrences of the value in cell E1. Copy this down column G and you will be able to see what values in E are also in F.

```
=COUNTIF(F:F,E1)
```

If you want to simplify the output a bit, you can use the if function

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F:F,E1)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried putting in your formula for the entire columns as =COUNTIF(E1:E5000, F1:F5000) and only had a few entries highlighted, and all of those showed duplicates within column F. Did I miss something? I need to find duplicates between the two columns.

Comment: Try the formula exactly as I have it above. The `COUNTIF` function takes two parameters, one which is the range to look through and `F:F` is the entire column F, and the second parameter is the value to search for, so `E1`. The formula will tell you if the value in `E1` is in column F. Then you copy the formula down as far as column E goes. Then you can just filter on the new column where the count is greater than 0.